# iOS Does ATS not support RSA key exchange for PFS?

Tags: ios, rsa, diffie-hellman

I recently set my info.plist about App Transport Security.

To prevent HTTP and allow HTTPS only, I turn off "Arbitrary allows Loads".

And I found certain site that I need to open by WKWebView, it shows

> didFailProvisionalLoadForFrame: frameID=3, domain=NSURLErrorDomain, code=-1200

I searched what problem is and I saw there is Perfect Forward Security issue.

Since I'm newbie about Network, I studied and there is a document about Key-change Algorithm.

One is RSA and another is Diffie–Hellman, and it said Diffie–Hellman support PFS, RSA not.

So my guess is Apple don't support RSA Key-Exchange, and have to turn off NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy to show site on WKWebView.

Am I right? and if so, why Apple don't support RSA Key-Exchange.

Is there no way to open without setting NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy?

Comment: What iOS version do you use for testing? What domains fail to load? Test the domains using https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ to see what TLS version and ciphers are supported.

Comment: Thanks! I go to ssllabs.com/ssltest and put a domain, and it said no Forward Security Support. It supports TLSv1.2, not 1.3 by the way.